# PHP Date Manipulations

Tags: php, datetime

I need to get previous 30 days from a specific date which is available from database(eg: 2010-05-23 12:36:29).I am try it by using

```
date('d', strtotime("-30 days"))
```

Which is getting the currect answer what i looking for but it is not help me to enter date from database.Please help me to solve the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Step by step:

```
$db_string =           "2010-05-23 12:36:26";
$db_timestamp =        strtotime($db_string);
$db_timestamp_30days = strtotime("-30 days", $db_timestamp);

$readable_date = date("d", $db_timestamp_30days);
```

Comment: Just as an alternative, it is possible to use `strtotime` this way as well: `strtotime("2010-05-23 12:36:26 -30 days")`